# Is there a way to specify where a game object spawns in the hierarchy in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, location, hierarchy, spawn

I have set up a random spawner that creates new game objects but they are being created outside of my canvas and therefore can't be seen when play the game. Is there any way to fix this? [The objects 'neg thoughts' are UI Buttons and are being created outside of the canvas even though I need them to appear on screen so they can be used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwmuV.png)

I did see a similar question but the suggestions didn't work for my problem.

this is very frustrating for me and any help would be awesome!

Comment: I wonder what the [parent parameter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) does.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply pass the `parent` into [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

> **parent**
>     Parent that will be assigned to the new object

```c#
var newObj = Instantiate(prefab, parentTransform);
```

or with additional transforms

```c#
var newObj = Instantiate (prefab, position, rotation, parentTransform);
```

---

Or as others already said you can still do it afterwards at any time either by simply assigning a new [`transform.parent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html)

```c#
newObj.transform.parent = parentTransform;
```

or using [`transform.SetParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

```c#
newObj.transform.SetParent(parentTransform, worldPositionStays);
```

The advantage of the later is that you have an optional parameter `worldPositionStays`

> **worldPositionStays**    If `true`, the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified such that the object keeps the same world space position, rotation and scale as before.

assigning a new

```c#
transform.parent = parentTransform;`
```

will always act the same way as

```c#
transform.SetParent(parentTransform);
```

since the default value for `worldPositionStays` (so if you don't explicitly pass it) is `true`.

---

So for the specific case of UI in a `Canvas` you could use

```c#
public TheSpawnComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Via the Inspector drag&drop any object here that is inside the canvas
    // or the canvas itself
    [SerializeField] private GameObject parentInCanvas;

    [SerializeField] private Button buttonPrefab;

    public void DoInstantiate()
    {
        var newButton = Instantiate (buttonPrefab, parentInCanvas);
        //Todo Position and callback
    }
}
```

Or if the spawner script is attached to an object inside the canvas anyway you could also spawn as child of this one directly using

```c#
var newButton = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, transform);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the transforms parent after you have created the game object.

```
spawnedObject.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use below code

```
public GameObject Prefab; // Object to Create
public Transform ParentOfObj;// Must Be inside the canvas or canvas it self
void Start()
{
    GameObject g = Instantiate(Prefab) as GameObject;
    g.transform.SetParent(ParentOfObj);
    g.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
}
```

Comment: The `as` for `Instantiate` is redundant, it returns the type of the given prefab anyway. What if the `localScale` is not supposed to be `Vector3.one`?